# PHP foreach in a function only runs once

Tags: php, arrays, function

I'm trying to run a foreach loop to check if one of the required fields in a form is empty, and output the missing fields through an error array. **Each of the variables is assigned to a $_POST variable.**

However, once I call the function:

```
fields_empty($requiredFields, $fieldErrors);
```

It only runs once, and not looping through the error. Here's the full source code:

```
$requiredFields = array(
    "First Name"=>$fname,
    "Last Name"=>$lname,
    "Email"=>$email,
    "Password"=>$pass1,
    "Confirm Password"=>$pass2,
    "Country"=>$country,
    "Address 1"=>$addr1,
    "City"=>$city,
    "State"=>$state,
    "Postal Code"=>$pcode,
    "Phone Number"=>$phone
);

$fieldErrors = array();

function fields_empty($requiredFields, $fieldErrors) {
    global $fieldErrors;
    foreach($requiredFields as $name => $field) {
        if (empty($field)) {
            array_push($fieldErrors, "$name is required.<br>");
            return true;
        }
    }
}

fields_empty($requiredFields, $fieldErrors);
print_r($fieldErrors);
```

Output in browser:

```
Array (
    [0] => First Name is required.
)
```

Also, this only happens when it's in a function. If I execute it without a function, it shows all the missing fields.

Comment: Why are you passing `$fieldErrors` as an argument ___and___ accessing it as a `global` as well? Just pass it as an argument `by reference`. But a `return` in the middle of a loop will `terminate` that loop

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove **return** from your function. What **return** does is terminate the function and return whatever is passed with the **return**, here its set to **true**. Removing **return** will keep the loop running.

```
function fields_empty($requiredFields, $fieldErrors) {
   global $fieldErrors;
   foreach($requiredFields as $name => $field) {
      if (empty($field)) {
         array_push($fieldErrors, "$name is required.<br>");
      }
   }
}
```